# TLS Certificate for AWS hosted page and external domain provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53

I'm trying to get a TLS certificate using AWS Certificate Manager. I bought my domain in the external domain registrar. I made a CNAME record over there: from `mytargetdomain.com` to `xxxxx.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com`. The second is the Application Load Balancer endpoint address which stands in front of my application.

Then I'm trying to get a TLS cert in AWS Certificate Manager on `mytargetdomain.com`. I'm choosing DNS validation, I'm adding CNAME record to the DNS configuration for the domain in Route 53. In route 53 I have also 2 other records created automatically by AWS for `mytargetdomain.com`.

The thing is that AWS Certificate Manager on `mytargetdomain.com` shows constantly `pending` status (now for many hours already). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

If your DNS is hosted externally, then you need to create the DNS validation record externally.   ACM uses a normal DNS query to check for the validation record, so Route 53 has no special privilege or standing.  A record in Route 53 does nothing unless that's where your DNS is actually hosted.